# Is it possible to change a close reason?

Tags: bug

The automatic comment left by the duplicate close reason doesn't start with a capital P and being the old, compulsory disorder Grammar Nazi I am, I tend to correct it all the time...

If one of the mods can change that in like 10 seconds, could you humour me, please???

If it takes longer then 25 seconds: Meh, I've gotten used to worse before.  **;-)**

Comment: That'd be an SE wide change and would require a developer.. I'm pretty sure this has been brought up before though. Let me see if I can find the post.

Comment: I agree, if it's a quickie let's do it!

Comment: @Seth: should I ask on [meta.se] then?

Comment: I would love this too as I recently voted but one put after mine was a better solution to the problem:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046210/ubuntu-keeps-upgrading-automatically-a-package-that-i-need-downgraded  But apparently this type of question has been asked before on the Stack Exchange:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction